# SQL Server allows select on exclusive locked table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, locking

Microsoft SQL Server 2019 CU 15.

In the first session I execute the following statements:

```
begin transaction
update Ledger set AmountDebit = 1000 where AccountId = 14
```

which creates exclusive lock on a table:
[image]

then in another session (in read commited isolation level) I run the following statements:

```
begin transaction
select * from Ledger where AccountId = 14
```

query executes immediately and returns results (of course the data in AmountDebit is still old, not 1000).

From my understanding this select statement should created a shared (S) lock which is not compatible with Exclusive (X) lock which is already on the table, and thus this select statement should be blocked and should not return the data (until the transaction in the first session is either commited on rolled back).

What am I missing? My knowledge in the locking is of course limited :)

Thanks.

Comment: that depends on the isolation level https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Relevant extract from link: *"SNAPSHOT transactions do not request locks when reading data. SNAPSHOT transactions reading data do not block other transactions from writing data. Transactions writing data do not block SNAPSHOT transactions from reading data."*

Comment: The schema stability (`SCH-S`) lock taken out by reads at RCSI has no conflict with `X` lock and only conflicts with schema modification (`SCH-M`) locks https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-ver16#lock_compatibility:~:text=Use%20the%20following%20table%20to%20determine%20the%20compatibility%20of%20all%20the%20lock%20modes%20available%20in%20SQL%20Server.